# The demand for the stock /The demand for stock or Demand for the stock?

Tags: noun-phrases

Context: a stock (traded in a stock exchange) was defined prior to the appearance of the following sentence:

The demand for the stock/the demand for stock/demand for the stock decreases significantly.

Question: which of the three phrases is suitable to use?

Comment: All may be suitable, depending on context and style preferrences.

Comment: Can you clarify with more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to a specific stock, say IBM, you may say:

> (The) Demand for the stock ( IBM  stock) is...

Comment: If "demand for the stock" then the violation of the rule that before a singular noun we need either a/an/ or the. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If a specific stock was defined previous to this sentence, and the sentence is referring back to that specific stock, then 2 is ineligible as written because it needs a further qualifier to indicate which stock it refers to (If it were referring to the market as a whole it would be suitable).

Of 1 and 3, more context is needed to determine if there is a clear preference, but the preference would only be in flow of the document/elegance, they are both valid otherwise.